# Registros duplicados en consulta SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

Holas
Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL Server:

```
SELECT P.ProyId, P.ProyCodigoSNIP, P.Proyecto, E.EtapaAbr
FROM PROYECTO AS P, PROYECTO_ETAPA AS PE, ETAPAS AS E
WHERE P.ProyId=PE.ProyId AND PE.ProyEtapa=E.EtapaId
```

Como verán, consulto de 3 tablas, pero los resultados se muestran duplicados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrían por favor apoyarme en qué debo incluir o modificar mi consulta para que no aprezcan los registros duplicados. Gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Es normal que te aparezcan registros duplicados. Fíjate que no son exactamente duplicados porque el campo `EtapaAbr` cambia de un registro al otro. Ya que tienes relaciones 1:n entre las tablas, es normal que recibas varios registros de la tabla relacionada por cada elemento de la tabla padre. Si no quieres tener `ProyId` duplicados entonces **dinos qué esperas recibir como resultado de la consulta** y te ayudaremos a montarla de manera adecuada a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Usando la clausula `DISTINCT`, del modo siguiente te debería bastar para filtrar los registros de manera única

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.ProyId, P.ProyCodigoSNIP, P.Proyecto, E.EtapaAbr
FROM PROYECTO AS P, PROYECTO_ETAPA AS PE, ETAPAS AS E
WHERE P.ProyId=PE.ProyId AND PE.ProyEtapa=E.EtapaId;
```

> Dentro de la sentencia este atributo ayuda a diferenciar los valores
>   que se encuentran duplicados y tomar solo uno de ellos, con lo cual tu
>   listado de registros debería solo tener registros únicos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Alfredo Paz, pero pruebo como indicas y me sigue mostrando los mismos resultados.
Creo que olvidé indicar que los Proyectos pueden tener dos etapas ya registradas y ahí es donde aparecen los duplicados.

Comment: @AlcibiadesPalestini puedes al final usar un GROUP BY para que de este modo aquellos registros que aparezcan mas de una ocasión se agrupen por P.proyecto por ejemplo